# Firefox address bar trying to open files

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, c++, google-search, address-bar

I frequently Google search the meaning of C++ functions and variables. For example, I want to google search `std::destroy_at` to navigate to the cppreference page.

In Chrome, typing `std::destroy_at` into the search bar and pressing enter performs a google search.

In Firefox, typing `std::destroy_at` into the search bar and pressing enter tries to open a file, see image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj5SW.png). One work-around is to type additional words before `std::`, but I am looking for a solution without additional typing.

How can I get Firefox to automatically use Google search for `std::destroy_at` and other C++ names (written in the form `word1::word2`) when typed into the address bar?

Comment: How about adding quotes around it like this: `"std::destroy_at"`

Comment: @Giacomo1968 usually I am copy-and-pasting code from another source (stackoverflow, my editor, or another cppreference page). I grab they mouse, copy the code, and open the firefox window. My right hand isn't on my keyboard, so I'm hoping for a solution that does not require extra typing.

Comment: Why not use the dedicated search box in Firefox? You may have to enable it.

Comment: @DanielB First, one large address bar is slightly faster since I  don't need to move my mouse so far across the screen to reach it. (On Ubuntu, you change windows on the left. In Firefox, the search bar is on the right. I could move the Ubuntu task bar to the right, but then it would be further from the back button, Activities, etc.) Second, it reduces visibility of the URL. This is  important since I often find myself needing to delete junk added to the end of the URL. (?noredirect=1 on SO) Third, two navigation boxes has the aesthetics of my grandma's 2005 installation of Internet Explorer.

Comment: The Search bar can be shrunk to take up little space and it can then be moved anywhere in the tool bar, keeping its size. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1049849